How to fix below error on BizTalk 2016 application?
How to fix below error on Biztalk 2016 application?

Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Converters.CreateBindingException: Unable to get binding type for binding extension "sqlBinding". Verify the binding extension is registered in machine.config.
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Converters.BindingFactory.GetBindingType(String wcfExtensions, String bindingName, Type& bindingElementType)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Converters.BindingFactory.CreateUserBinding(String wcfExtensions, String bindingName, String bindingConfiguration, String referencedBindings)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Converters.BindingFactory.CreateBinding(String wcfExtensions, String bindingName, String bindingConfiguration, String bindings)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Config.CustomTLConfig.CreateBinding(THConfig thConfig)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient2.InitializeValues(IBaseMessage message) at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfTransmitter2.GetClientFromCache(String spid, IBaseMessage message)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Run

How to fix above error on BizTalk 2016 application?

Have you checked this troubleshooting guide already?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/troubleshoot-installation-issues-with-the-sql-adapter#BKMK_SQLInvalidBinding
Please check if the sqlBinding is correctly registered there correctly and for the correct processor architecture.
Otherwise, please provide more details what you are trying to do and how your BizTalk Server is configured.
